# Controlling a nested tmux session from bash script

Tags: bash, tmux

I am trying to write a bash script to setup a tmux session session which contains 2 nested sessions which looks like the picture below.

x:  name for outer session

x-left: name for nested session on the left

x-right: name for nested session on the right

```
------------------------------
|   -----------  ----------   |
|  |          | |          |  |
|  |  x-left  | |  x-right |  |
|  |  pane 1  | |  pane 1  |  |
|   ----------| |----------   |
|  |          | |          |  |
|  | x-left   | |  x-right |  |
|  | pane 2   | |  pane 2  |  |
|   ----------   ----------   |
--------session name: x--------
```

The script I have so far is the following:

```
SESSIONNAME=$1

tmux new-session -s $SESSIONNAME \; \
   split-window -h \; \
   setw synchronize-panes \; \
   send-keys 'unset TMUX' C-m \; \
   setw synchronize-panes off \; \
   send-keys 'tmux new-session -s ' $SESSIONNAME-right C-m \; \
   select-pane -t 1 \; \
   send-keys 'tmux new-session -s ' $SESSIONNAME-left C-m \; \
   split-window -v \;
```

This works fine up until the last line in the script "split-window -v \;" which applies to the outer session. How can I control the nested sessions in this script?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the exact answer I was looking for, but a work around that worked for me was to first set up the tmux sessions I plan on using as nested sessions, and then lastly set up the outer host session and attach to the nested sessions from there. Here is the script I came up with to produce the environment describe in my original post:

```
SESSIONNAME=$1

# set up right hand side nested session, dont attach to it yet
tmux new-session -d -s $SESSIONNAME-right \; \
   rename-window remote-work \; \
   split-window -v -p 50 \; \
   setw synchronize-panes \; \
   send-keys 'clear' C-m \; \
   setw synchronize-panes off \;

# set up left hand side nested session, dont attach to it yet
tmux new-session -d -s $SESSIONNAME-left \; \
   rename-window local-work \; \
   split-window -v -p 50 \; \
   setw synchronize-panes \; \
   send-keys 'clear' C-m \; \
   setw synchronize-panes off \;

# attach and set up host session, and from there attach to nested sessions
tmux new-session -s $SESSIONNAME \; \
   set status off \; \
   split-window -h -p 50 \; \
   setw synchronize-panes \; \
   send-keys 'unset TMUX' C-m \; \
   setw synchronize-panes off \; \
   select-pane -t 0 \; \
   send-keys 'tmux attach -t ' $SESSIONNAME-left C-m \; \
   select-pane -t 1 \; \
   send-keys 'tmux attach -t ' $SESSIONNAME-right C-m \;
```